# What's wrong with my minimalist NodeJS setup?

Tags: linux, node.js, bash, logging

I don't know if I'm scarred for life by my experiences with Log4J or what, but I really would rather not get into Winston/Bunyan for handling logging in NodeJS.

So here's what I've come up with. I have a crontab job which starts my NodeJS app on reboot. It runs a bash script which looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

node /opt/dist/server/app.js 2>> /var/log/myapp/err.log | tee -a /var/log/myapp/out.log
```

And so my crontab looks like this:

```
*/1 * * * *     root    /root/bin/startup.sh
```

I found this in [the NodeJS documentation on console methods](https://nodejs.org/api/console.html), where it explains that stdout is non-blocking and stderr blocks. It also says this should be okay in production.

So far so good though. I'm going to let this run for a couple of days and see what happens. Is this a terrible idea? My biggest concern is that I was not aware that the pipe was non-blocking but the file-redirection is blocking. What else might I not know, that could possibly go wrong with this setup?

Comment: I wouldn't say that this is a terrible idea and also i am not sure if this would help either but have you checked forever => https://www.npmjs.com/package/forever , this module does at least 2 important things, first, it insures that your node script runs continuously, and second, it keeps a separate logging file (For both stdout and stderr) for every thread you run which might give you the chance to see what is going on.

Comment: i am 100% ready to use forever, was actually trying to make that work for me before I landed on this solution. it just would not write out the logfiles to where i wanted them. it was putting everything into its own logfile, even though I was passing it the -e and -l arguments with paths to /var/log/myapp/...it still all was logged to ~/.forever/<randomfilename>.log.

Comment: Perhaps a permssion issue prevented the -l option from taking place at /var/log , please try it out with /tmp , something like [forever start you_script.js -l /tmp/log] , this should be working just fine.

Comment: will try that. the box its on is barebones everything running as root, did a `ps aux | grep node` and it looked like everything running as root so I didn't bother to `chmod 777 /var/log/myapp` but i will.

Comment: so far so good. i've been running this setup for a week or so. the one problem was my startup script was overwriting log files, but i made some changes and now it appends to both err.log and out.log. i love bash.

Comment: If my comments helped you resolve your issue, please let me know so that i can post it as an answer and please accept it, as this might help the others someday.

Comment: it was unrelated to permissions @Ma'moonAl-Akash. if i could toss you some rep though i would. appreciate the effort.

Comment: No need, in all the ways, i am glad you have your issue resolved.